# Why My jQuery code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a HTML page and added jQuery in it but it is not working. Don't know What I am doing wrong. I also searched but my code looks right. but it is not working for me. 
My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("abc").fadeOut("fast");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .abc {
            background-color: #FEA2A2;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Click Me!</button>
    <div class='abc'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

According to the code, It should fade out the box when the button is clicked. But it is not happening.

Comment: You are missing a . before `abc`.

Comment: abc should be .abc as the selector

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2J872/

Comment: Yea, I just missed . :( It worked ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use prefix dot for class. you miss the dot for class

```
$(".abc").fadeOut("fast");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("abc").fadeOut("fast");
});
});
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$(".abc").fadeOut("fast");
});
});
</script>
```

As you are using class selector.

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
$("abc").fadeOut("fast");
```

to:

```
$(".abc").fadeOut("fast");
```

you have wrong jquery selector. you need to use dot (`.`) for class.

see <kbd>[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

For selector use `.` for class so :

Change

```
$("abc").fadeOut("fast");
```

TO

```
$(".abc").fadeOut("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error in your selector. prefix `.` for class selector

```
$(".abc").fadeOut("fast");
```